# Does an exponential map defined on all of $T_p M$ for one $p$ imply completeness?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a *connected* Riemannian manifold. Hopf-Rinow states that if $\exp_p$ is defined on all of $T_p M$ for **all** $p \in M$, then $M$ is geodesically complete.

I'm wondering whether it is sufficient for $\exp_p$ to be defined on the whole tangent space for **one** $p \in M$.
(If you go with the interpretation that geodesic incompleteness comes from "cuts" or "holes" in your manifold, then the exponential map should be able to "see" these.)

Comment: [Might be helpful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221414/example-of-the-manifold-with-a-non-surjective-exponential-map-at-a-point/3221502#3221502).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is sufficient, as explains Jack Lee in the comment I posted. You can find in his book *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature* the following corollary of Hopf-Rinow theorem.

> **Corollary 6.14:** If there exists one point $p ∈ M$ such that the restricted
>   exponential map $\exp_p$ is defined on all of $T_p M$, then $M$ is complete.

It is more a corollary of the proof of Hopf-Rinow, not really of the theorem itself.

Comment: There are also some formulations of Hopf-Rinow that make this explicit. I googled and found [Thomas_Franzinetti_38996.pdf](http://perso.eleves.ens-rennes.fr/people/Gwendal.Soisnard/Rapports_2016/Thomas_Franzinetti_38996.pdf) in which Hopf-Rinow (theorem 3.35) contains _four_ equivalent statement, and the one asked here, is called (C1).